# Is there a way to set up passwordless / passphraseless ssh so can only come from one client?

Tags: ssh, password-management

I know how to [set up passwordless / passphraseless ssh](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/ssh-keys.html).  But my understanding is that setting it up that way means that if someone get ahold of the id_dsa file, they can then log in from any machine.

Is it possible to set up, on server X, that Y is an "authorized key" only when it's coming from client Z?

Answer (score 3):

You may restrict access by IP for every authorized_key.
Just add the following line into `authorized_keys` on X something like:

`from="Z_IP" Y_id_rsa.pub`

In this case server X will be accessible via SSH using Y's key only when accessing from Z's IP-address.

Also, you may add additional parameters. Here is examples: https://debian-administration.org/article/685/Restricting_SSH_logins_to_particular_IP_addresses

Comment: Can I use a DNS entry "foo.com" as well, or does it have to be an ip address?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you should have `UseDNS` enabled in `sshd_config`:
`UseDNS yes`
But it may take some seconds for DNS-query finish on connection.